# windows 11 setup not showing disks

Tags: windows-11

My Windows 11 started always booting in "recovery mode" on my Acer laptop and it looks like it can no longer detect the hard drives.

I can see the hard drives in the BIOS menu and also installed Ubuntu on this laptop (from where I am typing this).  Ubuntu is able to access all disks without any problem.

I created a USB for booting Windows setup, but setup is unable to find any disk.

Comment: If you have installed Ubuntu on the disk that implies you deleted the partitions.  So when you installed Ubuntu did you enable CSM or keep it disabled?  If you enabled it then that implies you installed Linux in Legacy Mode (MBR) while keeping it disabled would imply UEFI Mode (GPT).  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment. Windows 11 requires Legacy Mode to be disabled, if you have installed Ubuntu while it was enabled, you will have to disable it and delete all partitions on the drive in order to install Windows 11 on the disk.

Comment: Another failed dual boot experiment. Run your other OS as a Virtual Machine running on your Windows 11 host machine.

Comment: @Ramhound looks like UEFI was enabled, because thought GRUB menu I can boot windows without any issues.